# How can I matche an string using regex with access and VBA

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I have this code, but when I use this, the UrlTest variable return the entire URL and not the capturing groups where I have defined in the regex. `^http:\/\/myanimelist\.net\/animelist\/(.*[^\/])(?:\/|)$`

Here is my code:

```
Private Function UrlTest(strUrl As String) As String
    'Do the regEx for get the user in url
    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    regEx.Pattern = "^http:\/\/myanimelist\.net\/animelist\/(.*[^\/])(?:\/|)$"
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = False

    If regEx.Test(strUrl) Then
        Dim matche As Object
        Set matche = regEx.Execute(strUrl)
        If matche.Count <> 0 Then
            UrlTest = matche(0)
        End If
    Else
        UrlTest = "false"
    End If
End Function
```

This function with strUrl with `http://myanimelist.net/animelist/example` as value return the same value, and not what I want: `example`.

I can't understand that ! You can see, this [Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/iR6xR3/1) work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UrlTest = matche(0).submatches(0)
```

You should try this.

Comment: I must wait Five minute X_x

Comment: up 1 for Vks while he awaits :)

Comment: @Vks `.Submatches(0)` is VBA's equivalent of `.Groups(1)` in Vb.net for capturing groups?

Comment: @JLILIAman may be...not sure....rest all places like python etc...`match.group(1)` works.Seems like so.